# How to assign values of a 2d array to 3d array in NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

I'm currently working on a 3d array called `X` of size `(100,5,1)`. I want to assign the randomly created 2d arrays called `s`, dimension of `(5,1)` to `X`. My code is like below.

```
for i in range(100):
    s = np.random.uniform(-1, 2, 5) 
    for j in range(5):
        X[:,j,:] = s[j]
```

I got 100 `(5,1)` arrays and they're all the same. I can see why I have this result, but I can't find the solution for this.

I need to have 100 unique `(5,1)` arrays in `X`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to simply create a `100 x 5 x 1` 3D matrix of the desired size in one go? `s = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=2, size=(100, 5, 1))`... especially since each `5 x 1` vector comes from the same probability distribution.  Why would you want to individually create 100 `5 x 1` arrays?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `X[i,j,:] = s[j]`?

Comment: @Divakar Yes. Yes it should.

Comment: yeah I just realized that it wasn't correct. It should be X[i,j,:] = s[j]. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are indexing the entire first dimension and thus broadcasting a single `5 x 1` array.  This is why you are seeing copies and it only remembers the last randomly generated `5 x 1` array you've created in the loop seen over the entire first dimension.  To fix this, simply change the indexing from `:` to `i`.

```
X[i,j,:] = s[j]
```

However, this seems like a bad code smell.  I would recommend allocating the exact size you need in one go by overriding the `size` input parameter into `numpy.random.uniform`.

```
s = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=2, size=(100, 5, 1))
```

Therefore, do not loop and just use the above statement once.  This makes sense as each `5 x 1` array you are creating is sampled from the same probability distribution.  It would make more sense in an efficiency viewpoint to just allocate the desired size once.

Comment: actually when I override the size parameter of s, I got broadcasting error. But it seems working well with only X[i,j,:] = s[j]

Comment: @kneazle The purpose of overriding `size` is so that you **don't** need to loop.  You just need to use the one statement.  Therefore, replace your entire code with `s = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=2, size=(100, 5, 1))`.  Using this code inside your loop will obviously give you broadcasting errors.

Comment: @kneazle No problem!  Good luck!